# How to ask the user if want to leave before doing something - Cordova with angular

Tags: angular, cordova

I'm trying to make an app for Android and iOS with Cordova and Angular2+

I need that if the user has started a video and wants to leave the screen ask if he  wants to mark the video as viewed.

I've tried

```
windows.onbeforeunload()
```

and also I've tried to do

```
console.log(this._location);
```

where this._location is instance of Location from  @Angular/common

because the user can move only to two screens from where I want to ask the question before leave, I tried to ask the question  on those two screen if the user comes from the desired one, but  I think that would leave holes like what happens if the users wants to close the application

any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Which developing framework are you using?

Comment: I'm developing both apps with Angular and Cordova